# python spyne complexModel with array of no type

Tags: soap, suds, spyne

I have a wsdl for which I am replicating the soap service using spyne. When I parse the wsdl using suds client, and create an object which is to be passed to a service method and print it, it shows:

```
   inqMultiRequest = 
      (TSYSMultipleInquiryRequestType){
         _reqID = ""
         inquireRequest[] = <empty>
      }
```

The inquireRequest is an array with no type defined. To model this with spyne model, I have TSYSMultipleInquiryRequestType defined as:

```
class TSYSMultipleInquiryRequestType(TSYSRequestMsgType):                            
      __namespace__ = DEFAULT_NS                                                       
      inquireRequest = Array
```

But it throws exception when running the wsgi server with the following:

> Exception: Invalid Array definition in
>   TSYSMultipleInquiryRequestType.inquireRequest

How should I model this with spyne where it can accept an array with no type defined?

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the issue resolved. Apparently the issue is how suds report the servie method and objects. The only thing that I required was to specify the max_occurs='inf' in the model. Without specifying the max_occurs, suds client factory creates a single instance of inquireRequest. With max_occurs, it creates it as an array to which I can add multiple

```
class TSYSMultipleInquiryRequestType(TSYSRequestMsgType):
    inquireRequest = TSYSInquiryRequestType.customize(
        nullable=False, min_occurs=0, max_occurs='inf')
```